# Combine Sheet 1 with Sheet 2 in Sheet 3 in the next available raw

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets that have the same header and i want to combine them in the third sheet considering always the next available cell as both sheets will have different size of data all the time.So i would like a VBA that will copy all available rows from Sheet 1 to Sheet 3( also if possible to delete N/A) then copy all available rows Sheet 2 (same remove N/A) to Sheet 3. Thanks for help!

My code look like this till now:

```
Sub cpynpst1()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh5 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, LR As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
LR = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A2:A" & LR)
rng.EntireRow.Copy sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below which would loop through the worksheets, get the information and move it to the third worksheet, then it would remove all the `#N/A`. While looping may not be the preferred method to solving your problem, it reduces repeating code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub cpynpst1()
Dim oWB As Workbook: Set oWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim destSH As Worksheet, LR As Long, destLR As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set destSH = oWB.Sheets("Sheet3")

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name = "Sheet1" Or ws.Name = "Sheet2" Then
    
        'Gets the last row of source and destination sheets
        LR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        destLR = destSH.Cells(destSH.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If destLR = 1 Then
            ws.Range("A1:O" & LR).Copy destSH.Range("A1")
        Else
            ws.Range("A2:O" & LR).Copy destSH.Range("A" & destLR + 1)
        End If
    End If
 Next ws
 
 'get the new last row of the destination ws
 destLR = destSH.Cells(destSH.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With destSH.Range("A1:O" & destLR)
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="#N/A", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    .AutoFilter
 End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Cleanup variables
Set oWB = Nothing
Set destSH = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony! Thanks for your help with this. Unfortunately it doesn't work and it's only brining the data in column A and not the rest of the table. I did used the code as it is but i will try again!

Comment: You can change the range of data you are pulling in. What is the range of data and what column would the N/As be in?

Comment: Both tables in Sheet 1 and 2 have data from A:O . And i need to delete the row if column D is N/A. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, Looking at you posted code it looked like you were only grabbing data from Column A, I have revised the code in the window to do what you want.

Comment: i am extremely sorry, it is my fault.I am trying it right now ! Thanks a lot again! Really appreciate all your help!